# How can i see the balance of my geth wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethminer

I am new to eth mining and i have some problem finding my balance.

I know that if you mine via pool you dont have to download the blockchain.

So, i downloaded geth, i made a new account and i am using this pool https://eth.pp.ua to mine with ethminer.

You can see my mining work here: 0x5654B64bD8Af7D053aC7705955Da287a150A6eF1

But how can i check my eth balance? When i give the command from the console to see my wallet's balance it returns me 0.

Must i sync the blockchain to my pc in order to see the balance?

Thanks!

Comment: So after three years the balance of that wallet is: 0.111941306438278672 Ether
Value:
$44.23 (@ $395.14/ETH) Is geth still running?

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ to check your balance without downloading the blockchain. Then select "View Wallet Info" > "View with Address Only".

Comment: But this is another wallet. I already have my wallet address created with geth. Is the: 0x5654B64bD8Af7D053aC7705955Da287a150A6eF1

Comment: @ManolisAvagiannis From MEW you can check the balance of your address, and you do not need to download anything.

Comment: It's showing 0 ETH. It doesnt show demical amounts or there is something wrong with my mining?

Comment: You should check with your minning pool if they provide statistics for your work submissions.

Comment: Here is the mining worker. There are shares stats. Is that ok?

https://eth.pp.ua/stats/miner/index.php?address=0x5654B64bD8Af7D053aC7705955Da287a150A6eF1

Comment: In that page the balance is 0.0043, the pool help page says the payment are done once a day if your balance is above 0.1. So they will not pay until you balance is higher, you should ask your pool if you have more doubts.

Comment: This is estimated. It didnt give me anything yet. I think it's because of what you say. My balance is still under 0.1 and also they pay once a day. I am just anxious of done anything wrong and all these hours is mining for nothing. So the rewards are calculated with no problem?

Comment: I have the same question. I have some ethereum in my wallet (as per the check balance on above) but when I check using geth console (eth.getBalance('0xMyEthAddress')) I get the balance as 0. Is there any sync that needs to happen with my local geth wallet?

Comment: Usually payments are delayed until a target is reached and are paid once or twice a day, to minimize transactions fees. Check the pool FAQ for the minimum payment or ask the pool operator. They may allow transfer for a lower amount.

Answer (score 2):

By going to https://etherscan.io/ and entering the public address of your wallet you can view your account balance.

Further, you can put your account on a watch list and receive notifications from the site when your address receives a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but answers not really answering the direct questions regarding Geth and alt-coin Go Ethereum builds.

Yes, you must sync completely to view an account balance and/or work with it.
To see if it's synced via console:
> `eth.syncing`
- Anything besides "false" means you are NOT synced.

You may want to also read these posts:

- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24669/22785
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16697#issuecomment-387152942
  In other words, if you got a slow machine you may never sync the Ethereum chain.