# Using jsonrpc to get eth data but the result is null

Tags: ether, json-rpc

I use this command to get data from eth network, but get null return
[image]

---

The command is

> curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}' localhost:8545 -H 'content-type: application/json'

The output is

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0x0"}

Comment: Can you post the code here (in text), I can't access the image from where I am.

Comment: You said you get a "null" result, but you don't. You get a JSON response with the correct ID and the result 0. I assume that this is because the current block number on the node you're connecting to is 0.

Comment: curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}' http://localhost:8545  -H 'content-type: application/json'  and the output is {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0x0"}    I have downloaded all the blocks, the result should not be 0

Comment: Is your node fully synced? A node syncing in fast mode will not return meaningful data until it has finished (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete).