# Result of getting information from ethereum is null

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nethereum, c#

I am writing a simple smart contract using Nethereum using this solidity code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

After using `Nethereum.Autogen.ContractApi` Nuget Package I autogenerate the service of it.
I got the code from this link: https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-net-developers-workflow-for-creating-and-calling-ethereum-smart-contracts-44714f191db2

Piece of testing code that I use:

```
using BlockchainPoc.SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage;
using BlockchainPoc.SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.ContractDefinition;
using Nethereum.RPC.Eth.DTOs;
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlockchainPoc
{
    class Program
    {
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://localhost:7545";
            var privateKey = "0x6352ebaeef4bfe298789ae7dceb62bd9bd2fdf47b7c4b9ec2997d271482953f9";
            var account = new Account(privateKey);
            var web3 = new Web3(account, url);

            Console.WriteLine("Deploying...");
            var deployment = new SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorageDeployment();
            var receipt = await SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorageService.DeployContractAndWaitForReceiptAsync(web3, deployment);
            var service = new SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorageService(web3, "0x8B0AB0dA433E2Eb05CEA17DB4Cd99E62b4a740DC");
            Console.WriteLine($"Contract Deployment Tx Status: {receipt.Status.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Contract Address: {service.ContractHandler.ContractAddress}");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Sending a transaction to the function set()...");
            var receiptForSetFunctionCall = await service.SetRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(
                new SetFunction() { X = 42, Gas = 400000 });
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished storing an int: Tx Hash: {receiptForSetFunctionCall.TransactionHash}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished storing an int: Tx Status: {receiptForSetFunctionCall.Status.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            var latestBlockNumber = await web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockNumber.SendRequestAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Latest block number", latestBlockNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Calling the function get()...");

            var block = await web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber.SendRequestAsync(latestBlockNumber);

            var intValueFromGetFunctionCall = await service.GetQueryAsync(new BlockParameter(latestBlockNumber));
            Console.WriteLine($"Int value: {intValueFromGetFunctionCall} (expecting value 42)");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    }
}
```

[image]
Seems that I have the same issue like here [Using jsonrpc to get eth data but the result is null](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44586/using-jsonrpc-to-get-eth-data-but-the-result-is-null), but I don't see the solution.
In Ganache after the deployment of the contract and setting the value I see blocks created.
Also if I try to decode TXData I see correct values:
[image]

But in the end I am not able to see the result. Can you help me?

This is the json that is sent and returned with getting request.

[image]

And decoded data of the request:
[image]