# Should I wait for sync to be 'finished' in 'syncmode=light' before I could check account balance OR transact using the account?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, accounts, balances, rinkeby

*NOTE: I'm aware of another [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete), but, it's related to 'fast' syncmode, and mine is of 'light' syncmode.*

I'm running light node client for rinkeby using command:

`geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi personal,db,net,eth,web3 --syncmode=light`

There was a break of more than 7 hours and after the restart, the current state of 'sync':

`> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 504738,
  highestBlock: 2408225,
  knownStates: 1149444,
  pulledStates: 1142442,
  startingBlock: 482170
}`

I've two personal accounts, on rinkeby and they both have some ether:

[0xf5120faca20afab4628c0270cff819348f612d6e](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf5120faca20afab4628c0270cff819348f612d6e) has 18.589374 Ether 
[0xde51c26902f78a69bc3a5143d19e9dcff8607520](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xde51c26902f78a69bc3a5143d19e9dcff8607520)  has 3.1605 Ether

But, in my local console the balance is shown as 0, why?

```
> eth.accounts
["0xf5120faca20afab4628c0270cff819348f612d6e", "0xde51c26902f78a69bc3a5143d19e9dcff8607520"]
> web3.eth.getBalance('0xf5120faca20afab4628c0270cff819348f612d6e')
0
> web3.eth.getBalance('0xde51c26902f78a69bc3a5143d19e9dcff8607520')
0
```

Should I wait for sync to be 'finished' in 'syncmode=light' before I could check account balance OR transact using the account?

*NOTE: I'm aware of this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete), but, it's related to 'fast' syncmode, and mine is of 'light' syncmode.*

Comment: It's because the lack of a sync, not the way that it's being done. The question being linked should fix this problem.

Comment: Yes. Request to reopen after if that's not the case.

Comment: @Meshugah, please add that as an answer. I'll accept it. Definitely, this answer is different than the one found in the linked question. Since, the linked question refers it as 'behaviour of fast syncmode'.

Comment: Haha I appreciate it. However, I can't as the question is closed.

Comment: Regarding the transactions, yes , you can send a transaction to a peer, if you already have the DHT with addresses. Even if it states that you don't have ethers on those accounts. A peer will have access to your balance and if the tx is correctly signed, it will go onto the next block.