# Check account ballance in go ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to get balance of my account on test ropsten network but currently i am confused a bit . I have synchronised geth server on ropsten network and have sent from my other wallet to wallet that i have created in geth using mist wallet. My wallet there is:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa340ac939b0ab504a9a0bcef337ff0f8172a910e

And I have sent to it 1 rETH from 0x68f4d98bbcc1e11351edfaf7de7782cf3f44c9bc account.

I was block 3396592 and I am shure that my eth have already synchronized this information .

```
> web3.eth.getBlock(3396592)
  // .... shows me block information with 
  transactions: [ .... "0x012d98ddcd6073b9fbcda88867ba9e44a99698d047d00ddfe48d9078107e4604" ... ]
  ...
```

And even more i can see this transaction :

> web3.eth.getTransaction("0x012d98ddcd6073b9fbcda88867ba9e44a99698d047d00ddfe48d9078107e4604")
>   {
>     blockHash: "0xb806fa78a958ede78e32c23f8d9a6ba09735be401586a51da3bba72db0bdecb5",
>     blockNumber: 3396592,
>     from: "**0x68f4d98bbcc1e11351edfaf7de7782cf3f44c9bc**",
>     gas: 21000,
>     gasPrice: 1000000000,
>     hash: "0x012d98ddcd6073b9fbcda88867ba9e44a99698d047d00ddfe48d9078107e4604",
>     input: "0x",
>     nonce: 0,
>     r: "0xbd6d4d51c42d7e87c0aec8fa4fade9320a84c98f6a5ecd87e44bef7d5151c8ae",
>     s: "0x75273a8e3b4d8d2c93a7c89d4b93934cb08ec775567b578014a3d4fd33ed43d1",
>     to: "**0xa340ac939b0ab504a9a0bcef337ff0f8172a910e**",
>     transactionIndex: 10,
>     v: "0x2a",
>     value: 1000000000000000000
>   }

But get balance shows me always 0 ETH:

> // balance of my local account
>   eth.getBalance("0x4168eAE10bF4CBEdB34237fc858A5BBEb03f0Be9")
>   0
>   eth.getBalance("0x68F4D98bbcC1e11351EdfaF7DE7782cF3F44c9Bc")
>   0

The question what i am doing wrong.

**UPD:**

I have read this question [Why is my ether balance 0 in geth, even though the sync is nearly complete?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete) , that seems looks like my. And now i have removed and resynchronized my database without fast' flag but with the same effect. I already have my block but all balances are zeros. I have 72 blocks behind tail and never reach fully synched state.

Comment: What does `eth.blockNumber` return? If it doesn't return a number close to the last block of the chain at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/, then your node has not finished syncing. The more frequent problem is that it will require lots of disk IO to build the world state and it will take a lot of time. A very fast SSD is a must, geth currently doesn't support syncing with HDD.

Comment: @Ismael: eth.blockNumber is about 100 blocks behind end .