# can't read past event logs

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, synchronization, events

```
    const event = contractInst.Transfer({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

    events.get(function (error, result) { 
        if (!error) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

The get callback is called immidiately and always returns an empty array.

I synced rinkeby on my local machine (fast mode):

```
> eth.syncing 
{
  currentBlock: 2695904,
  highestBlock: 2695974,
  knownStates: 5468913,
  pulledStates: 5466381,
  startingBlock: 1062319
}
```

All the transfer events are shown on etherscan:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf736de997449df5cd756c34858747786e98bcd3d#events

**EDIT:**

It works if I use an external node (like using metamask to fetch web3). I'm using Geth to sync my node with the following command:

```
geth --rinkeby --syncmode=fast --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal
```

To connect the node I'm doing:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my ether balance 0 in geth, even though the sync is nearly complete?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete)

Comment: In fast mode until the sync has finished you cannot rely on the data being complete.

Comment: I will try to find out if it is the same reason. When using an external node like `new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io:443'));` the events should be listed right?