# sendRawTransaction insufficient funds while there is enough balance

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, raw-transaction, rlp, sendrawtransaction

Sorry I probably create a topic that was answered multiple times but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to use RPC server of Geth to send a raw transaction. I've an address with a balance enough and a private key for that address, so I'm trying to call sendRawTransaction and it throws an error "insufficient funds for .. blabla". I have encoded the raw transaction correctly (I believe) since rlpdump shows a correct output. Please help me to find a reason what is happening

- What do I have:

  1. The latest version of Geth is running in the fast mode
  2. 99.99% synchronization
  3. An address with 0.5 Ether and a private key of that address
  4. An address of a recipient
  5. C++ client application that uses the RPC server of Geth

I encoded the following fields of the raw transaction according to RLP:

- Nonce (since there weren't any transactions from the address I've set it to 0x0)
- Gas price (Getting it from RPC server by appropriate method, 0x3b9aca00 Wei)
- Gas limit (Getting it from the latest block, now it is 5000)
- Address of the recipient
- Amount in Wei (I'm trying to send 0.05 Ether so it's 0xb1a2bc2ec50000 Wei)
- Empty string

Then I calculate Keccak-256 hash from that RLP encoded byte array and sign the hash by the private key by using ECDSA from OpenSSL. Afterwards I append V value to the RLP encoded byte array (V = chaindID * 2 + 35 = 37) and both R and S from calculated signature.

Then I convert the total byte array to hex string, prepend it with 0x prefix and send it to the RPC Server by JSON RPC request eth_sendRawTransaction. And finally I get the error insufficient funds. Please any ideas how to solve it, thanks in advance

**P.S.:** Please don't show me examples of EthereumJS usage and same libraries for other languages, I don't need any libraries, I'm just trying to understand how should it work in details

**UPD:** The problem was in wrong signature calculation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my ether balance 0 in geth, even though the sync is nearly complete?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete)

Comment: You will not be able to send transaction if the synchronization has not finished.

Comment: I thought there is a miner only can obtain a fully synchronized node. I've tried the light mode but there were some problems with getTransaction and getBlock methods, I don't remember exact error messages. For example, in Bitcoin I could send a transaction while the blockchain is not synchronized fully

Comment: By the way, I tried to push a raw transaction data to Etherscan.io, and it says also insufficient funds

Comment: It is strange that Etherscan.io fails... can you try to decode a sample raw transaction with https://blockchains.tools/rawTransactionDecoder?l=ETH? perhaps the RLP encoding is wrong, also there are certain requirements that have to be enforced when ECDSA signing in Ethereum s<n/2 (where is the parameter from ECDSA). As an alternative to running your node you can use Infura.io.

Comment: What was the issue with your signature ? Can you elaborate ? I've ran into the same issue.