# fast sync mode node does not work?

Tags: go-ethereum

I already have my light nodes working but in fast sync mode does not work the version of geth 1.9.3, I got these settings

Geth Version: 1.9.13-stable 
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.13
Operating System: linux
GOPATH= GOROOT=/usr/local/go

and I already downloaded all blockchain without errors or stoping the sync, but at the end does not work, show me all transactions and blocks details by by hash or other operations but wallet's balance = 0 does not work :(

thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my ether balance 0 in geth, even though the sync is nearly complete?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I understand from the link is what the blockchain gets updated very quickly and get changed 200 per second could reproduce memory lack, but I got a good machine with almost 15GB of ram and 2 Core and did not get halt or laggy

Comment: If you have a non-zero balance and it returns zero then it hasn't finished syncing. Geth sometimes stops syncing when it doesn't have enough peers, restarting geth may help.

Comment: ok, I will try again, thanks for the response.